# Database Validation

Tags: android, sqlite

i am adding values in database through coding. I want that if values have already being added in the database, it should not be added again. How can i put such validation.

My database table is:

```
  final String DATA="create table if not exists Favorites5("+"id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+"title TEXT,"+"employer TEXT,"+"location TEXT,"+"description TEXT,"+"city TEXT,"+"province TEXT,"+"lat TEXT,"+"log TEXT);";
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: remove autoincrement then you already added primary key na sure it will work for id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved . I am posting my code that i did for anyone who needs it.

check=0;
            try {
                Cursor cur = db.query("Favorites7", 
                        null, null, null, null, null, null);

```
             cur.moveToFirst();
              while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                    //name.append("n" + cur.getString(1));
                   //mylist.addAll(cur.getString(i));
                title1.add(cur.getString(1));

                            //nextScreenData.add(cur.getString(2).toString());
                    cur.moveToNext();
                }


                cur.close();
                for(int index=0; index<title1.size();index++)
                   {
                System.out.println(title1.get(index));
                   } 
                   System.out.println("AAAAA"+str1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        check=1;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Jobs added",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    adtofav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int flag=0;
            // Adding values to database
            if(check==0)
            {
            for(int j=0;j<title1.size();j++)
                { 
               if( str1.equals(title1.get(j)))
               {
                   flag=1;
                   break;
               }

                }
            }
             if(flag==1)
             {
                 /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Jobs already added",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); */
                 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(JobDesc.this);
                  dialog.setTitle("FAVORITES DATA");
                  dialog.setMessage("Data Already Exists");
                  dialog.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                  dialog.show();
             }else
             {try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


                    values.put("title", str1);
                    values.put("employer",employee);
                    values.put("location", loc);
                    values.put("description",desc);
                    values.put("city",city);
                    values.put("province",province);
                    values.put("lat",lat);
                values.put("log",log);
                    db.insert("Favorites7",null, values);
                    db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(JobDesc.this);
                  dialog.setTitle("FAVORITES DATA");
                  dialog.setMessage("Data Already Added");
                  dialog.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                  dialog.show();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
             }
        }
        });
```

Here Favorites 7 is my database table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is supported by Android, but you could use triggers.

The [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) explains how to use them in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a PRIMARY KEY constraint on "id", so the database will prevent you from entering two rows that have the same value in the column "id".

If you want to prevent duplicates in some other column, use a UNIQUE constraint on that column. For example, to prevent duplicates in your "title" column use

```
create table if not exists Favorites5(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT UNIQUE,                     -- Title can't be duplicated.
    employer TEXT,
    location TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    province TEXT,
    lat TEXT,
    log TEXT
);
```

Consider using NOT NULL constraints on all these columns, too.